# How to properly read device data from /dev/input/*?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clojure

I am trying to consume data from a gaming controller connected to my linux desktop and output it as it comes using Clojure, similar to what the command `cat /dev/input/js0` does.

I have the following code, however it does not output event data as it comes like the `cat` command does:

```
(with-open [r (clojure.java.io/input-stream "/dev/input/js0")]
  (loop [c (.read r)]
    (print c)
    (recur (.read r))))
```

What happens is the event data only gets printed out in chunks after repeatedly clicking buttons several times, it is not continuous like with the `cat` command. How do I get the events as they come so that I can print them immediately?

Comment: Have you tried with `reader` and `line-seq` or `.readLine`?

Comment: `.read` reads the next byte of data- what is the size of data of one button click? You can also try [JInput](https://github.com/jinput/jinput), Java library for joystick input.

Comment: The issue is like that the InputStream is buffered. clojure.java.io/input-stream returns buffered streams by default according to its docstring. Can you try FileInputStream?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! As it turns out, the issue was my use of `print` for some reason. When I switched to using `println` I could see the output as it came from my controller!

Answer (score 0):

For reasons I do not understand, when I switched to using `println` instead of `print` I could see the output in real time. My understanding is that both methods are the same except for the new line from `println`, so not sure why `print` lagged to output to the repl and `println` did not.

In any case, using `println` fixed my issue and I can now print data from my controller as I use it.

Comment: `println` flushes the output, `print` doesn't.